Is ‘the’ used before a number as determiner, when ‘all’ is used before them?
I want to write this sentence in a paper:

All the three characters also have their counterparts in ASCII,

where all the three characters refers to the aforementioned three characters out of a bigger set of characters.
Grammarly suggests that the should be removed to form all three characters (shown in the following figure), but I do not understand why. I understand that simply saying the three characters is correct, as the is a referring determiner, three a quantifying determiner, and they can be used together. Then, I want to put all before them to mean the three characters as a whole.

Thanks to @fev, I found another post in which three answers have discussed the differences between all three and all the three. However, I found them contradictory with each other:

Colin Fine’s answer states that all the three cars implies the three cars are not the entire class. The answer also states that all three cars does not exclude this possibility.
HannahRose, on the other hand, maintains that "all three cars implies that there are only three cars," which does not agree with the first answer. HannahRose also emphasises the fact that "All three cars already implies that you are referring to specific cars."
Prof. John Lawler’s answer makes the situation more confusing, because it states that the two phrases are equal in meaning. Although his answer was not voted up, I looked into Prof. John Lawler’s profile and found that he was an English grammarian.
I also did some investigation myself. I found in Cambridge English Dictionary an entry for all:


All means ‘every one’, ‘the complete number or amount’ or ‘the whole’.
...
All with no article
When all refers to a whole class of people or things, we don’t use the:

All children love stories. (i.e. every child in the world)
Not: All the children love stories.


Also an entry for determiners,

What do determiners do?
Determiners have two main functions: referring and quantifying.

According to the findings of my investigation, all three characters and all the three characters are all grammatically correct, but they have different meanings. all three implies that the three are a whole set, but all the three implies that the three are out of a bigger set, which is what I wanted to express.
However, it is obvious that this conclusion does not agree with Colin Fine’s and Prof. Lawler’s answers to some extent. Given that Prof. Lawler was an American, it is possible that the grammar for this use case is different in Britain and in American. But I do not know for sure. Anyway, I would like to request a definitive answer on the differences between all the three and all three.

Does this answer your question? Which is right — "all the three" or "all three" in a situation of specific objects?

@fev Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry for not seeing that question when I post mine -- it did not pop up as I typed my title. The discussion there can answer my question 1, but I also want to know an answer for my question 2.

It's not always easy to find duplicates to your own question. That's why the other users try to help. Maybe you want to edit your question to concentrate on the second issue then?

There isn't a 'rule' for everything - it's just 'the way we say it'.

@KateBunting I am not sure. I am not a native English speaker, so my education of English was established based on grammatical rules and so forth. But perhaps you are right. In that case, I would like to ask which way is preferred in formal writing, and I have edited my question to reflect your comment.

This Ngram shows that all three is very much more common than all the three.  As I said, I don't think this is because of a grammatical rule, it's just the way the language has evolved.

When you edit a question, please make it a coherent whole: don't pepper it with "Edit". The edit history is available if someone wants to see what's changed. Trying to make sense of ad-hoc additions simply makes it more difficult to answer. If the question needs improving, just change or add to the bits which need changing.

@AndrewLeach Fair enough. I did not realise that my approach decreased the readability. I will compose all my edits into my post as a whole later. There's one thing I want to ask, though. My question failed to reopen because "original close reason(s) were not resolved."  Was the failure a result of my format or did I fail to address the reasons anyway?

@GuanyumingHe I think it's the formatting. If it's written as "I have this question; Grammarly found this but Answer A says that [and quote the relevant bit], and Answer B says the other [with relevant quote again]. What is a comprehensive answer?" there's a good chance it will get re-opened. Just make the question flow logically from start to end.

There is elision of the word "of": "All of the three..."

If you use "all the three", it needs to be specific.
The specific rule is just about the only reliable one: "All the three characters I pointed out also have counterparts in ASCII". But many others do not."
This specificity can also be stated like this:
"all of the three characters I pointed out etc."
all of these or those three characters I pointed out
If there is a relative clause like that as in [all the three characters (that) I pointed out], the "the" is justified. It functions the same as: All those/these characters I pointed out
Versus: "All three characters also have counterparts in ASCII". etc. That's the difference. Specificity with a relative clause, for example.

"All three characters also have counterparts in ASCII." [general]
"All of the [or those, these] three characters also have counterparts in ASCII." [specific,  pragmatically, as opposed to other characters that are not ASCII]
"All three of the [or those, these] characters also have counterparts in ASCII" [specific, pragmatically, same as 2)]
"All the three characters I pointed out have counterparts in ASCII" [but not, for example, the ones I didn't point out or other ones somebody else mentioned]

For me, 2, 3 and 4 are semantically the same. They are specific.
"the"  as definite or specific
The is used to refer to a specific or particular member of a group. For example, "I just saw the most popular movie of the year." There are many movies, but only one particular movie is the most popular. Therefore, we use the.
grammar from Purdue University
Another example:
Imagine a game played in the street.

All boys on the street must be wearing shoes. [a general idea]

All the boys on the street must be wearing shoes.
[those specific boys but not, for example, the boys in gardens along that road]

All the dogs on the beach must be leashed. [implies dogs elsewhere do not need to be leashed. It refers to those four].

All dogs on the beach must be leashed. [a general statement].



Really appreciate the answer. A few questions: 1) You implied that I should have used either an of in between all and the, or a relative clause, to make the the in my original sentence more specific. Is my understanding correct? 2) Pragmatically, when someone sees my original usage (all the three characters ...), is the person likely to realise that I was referring to the specific three characters?

@GuanyumingHe 1) Yes 2) All the three characters [either previously mentioned] OR [that we are discussing here]. I use those square brackets to show something must follow the phrase but those are just examples. Not actual phrasing. Does that make sense?

It makes sense. I will accept your answer, although I am not so sure about the effect of of after all. Cambridge English Dictionary suggests that "We often use of after all in definite noun phrases (i.e. before the, possessives and demonstratives), but it is not obligatory." (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/all?q=All+of)

With all due respect: it isn't obligatory. I just gave you three options: All of the three characters did x; All the three characters we discussed did x; All three characters [with or without "we discussed" did x. Cambridge does not explain the second, as it is somewhat unusual.
